# Bot doesn't want to show id of a channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want bot to print id of the channel that member connected to.

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channelid = discord.VoiceChannel.id
    print(f'{channelid}')
```

When I am joining this channel I get this:

```
<member 'id' of 'VoiceChannel' objects>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to get `VoiceChannel` id, and `VoiceChannel` is a class, not an actual channel. For getting the id of the voice channel, you can use `before.channel.id` or `after.channel.id`. It depends on what you want to do. So you can change your code like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channelid = before.channel.id
    print(f'{channelid}')
```

As far as I know, if member joins the voice channel, then `before.channel.id` returns `None` and if member leaves the voice channel, then `after.channel.id` returns `None`.